# Is it Appstore save to subclass a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, ios5, subclass, subclassing

In different threads I read that it is not recommended to subclass an `UINavigationController`.
But is it AppStore save if I would do it? Has anyone any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have published a subclass of navigation controller that does exactly this.

Check out at: https://github.com/vitorll/CustomNavigationController

With these class I already published three apps in the appstore. And I know at least one friend that have used it in another 2 apps already approved by Apple.

If you need more help, let me know.